# Obtaining a copy of Hawking's Ph.D thesis - Properties of Expanding Universes

Tags: general-relativity, universe, specific-reference, big-bang, singularities

Due to its popularity, I am interested to know the 4 chapter titles and topics covered in S.W. Hawking Ph.D, [Properties of Expanding Universes](http://search.lib.cam.ac.uk/?itemid=|manuscrpdb|39780). I also ask this because that thesis is hardly available.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited for [hsm.se]?

Comment: There's limited information in "Stephen Hawking: A Life in Science" - it describes it as a "messy effor" with "holes and unanswered questions", but it was saved by the final chapter, which I think contained a singularity theorem

Comment: [Direct PDF link](http://schema.lib.cam.ac.uk/PR-PHD-05437_CUDL2017-reduced.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

It seems it went online at last! It went global and public, and it collapsed the wave-function! Here https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/251038

From this, the chapter titles are...

- Title: Properties of expanding universes.
- Abstract.
- Introduction.
- Acknowledgements.
- Chapter 1. The Hoyle-Narlikar theory of    gravitation.
- Chapter 2. Perturbations.
- Chapter 3. Gravitational    radiation in an expanding universe.
- Chapter 4. Singularities.
- References.

Comment: Glad you found it. May I suggest you combine this with your other answer into a single "answer with reference"?

Comment: It is done! Thanks! I wonder if Hawking himself had something to do with the free access to his Ph.D... I would love to know if he read us and decided to upload it all! :)

Comment: Where is the highest resolution and uncompressed version currently available?

Answer (score 2):

Every thesis submitted for a PhD in Cambridge is archived at the Cambridge University Library. They should be able to get you a copy (for a fee).

See http://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/deptserv/manuscripts/dissertations.html

Comment: they might let you come to the university library and look at it, but it isn't borrowable (see the link in the question) and i don't see any indication that they hold/share an electronic copy

Comment: found on google https://www.worldcat.org/title/properties-of-expanding-universes/oclc/62793673 . It gave me on the right the closest three libraries where they have it on microfilm. Try calling them if you want to read it.

Comment: the link has a facility for checking if a copy exists in the nearest libraries. Seems the closest to greece is UK and  illinois